# Android OutOfMemory exception - Is there another approach for my needs?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory, android-drawable

My app is loading a large image (a house floorplan), then drawing touch-reactive objects (furniture, lamps etc.) on the image. I have a base image file included with my app but the objects come from coords in my database.

I've successfully deployed the app in multiple iterations, but now I need to use larger base images and `BitmapFactory` is causing an `OutOfMemory` exception on many devices (both old and new devices; anything with < 32MB heap seems to crash).  I've read the 157 OOM questions on SO, but I'm afraid the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) they all seem to point to won't help me since resolution / zooming is critical to the app's function.

I've tried to test the device's available memory before loading, but the results are spotty at best (some devices like the galaxy S3 report plenty of heap but still crash).  I've also tried decreasing resolution but the image became unusable when reduced to a safe size based on the above test.

Is there another way to implement this design without ever using bitmaps?
I need to:

- Load large base image
- Create clickable shapes on top of the base image, maintaining their position / scale relative to the base image
- *BONUS*: in the iOS version of my app, I can do SVG-style text scaling so a long label on a small object will stay inside the object
  instead of running across the map(and will be invisible until the
  image is zoomed).  Replicating this in android would make me a happy
  code monkey.

I can post code if needed, but you've all seen it before (almost all of it came from SO).

Thanks in advance for reading, and for any help you can give.

Comment: Use tiles (small fragments of your image) Google Maps does the same.

Comment: You could store your bitmap as a sets of tiles at different resolutions, like Google Maps, and just load the tiles that are currently visible.  Another option would be to implement it like a game, using OpenGL.  There are lots of examples for game engines that can manage large game worlds.

Comment: I've seen OpenGL, but never used it.  Can you recommend a good tutorial?

Comment: @user1810544 - There's lots to learn.  Start with Google's Android documentation.  After that, you'll need to decide if you want to code all of the OpenGL from scratch, or use a 3rd party game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a few  options:

1. break your large image into tiles, load these tiles into an array, and move a camera object around and only load tiles that need to be drawn, as the comments suggest.
2. make your image small and scale it up using 'android:scaletype`
3. Draw lines and curves on a `Canvas` object at runtime.
4. Use OpenGL

The appropriate solution really depends on how you want it to  look.  Tiling will take more dev effort but will look better, just be careful that you are properly cleaning up any tiles that aren't being drawn...

dynamically scaling will be easier, but you cannot guarantee the image won't be blurry.

Drawing on a `Canvas` object at runtime could work well-- just use Lines of different width and circles and Rects etc.

Using OpenGL will have the steepest learning curve, and might be overkill.  This depends on your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look into using a "largeHeap" 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

1) Use tiles.  Use tiles and dynamically load your data.  Honestly, this is the best solution.  With this solution you can load arbitrarily large images.

I've successfully used this approach for an endless paint canvas and it works quite well.  You really only need to draw what is directly visible to the user.  Tiles is a way to cast away pieces you don't need.  A pyramid of tiles (where you pre-downsample your images and create more tiles), allows you to do this in a clean and fast way.

2) Use native code.  The memory restrictions on native code are not the same as Java code.  You can get away with allocating more memory.

3) Use OpenGL.  Once again, the memory restriction for OpenGL are not the same as Java code.

4) Convert your original plan to an SVG and use an SVG library like [this](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) one.

5) Use "largeHeap".  I strongly discourage this, as I think a largeHeap is rarely the solution, there are generally cleaner ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is static , you might wish to use this nice library:

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout

if the library doesn't support auto-downsampling of the image, you should do it by yourself, in order to use the best image for the current device (so that you won't get OOM).

for auto-sizing text , you might have some luch with the next post:

[Auto-fit TextView for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android/17786051?noredirect=1#17786051)