# Same configuration/different size yet screen does not scale from Samsung 10" to Nexus 7

Tags: android

I developed my app on a Samsung GT-P7510 (10.1" WXGA 1280x800 pixels). When I download to the Nexus 7 (7" 1280x800 pixels) the buttons that I use appear to be about the same physical size. The Nexus buttons are about 95% of the Samsung buttons. The rest of the screen seems to work OK- the text is in the right location and is proportionately smaller because that is defined in terms of screen height.

All my button sizes are defined using "dp" settings in the XML layout files. I would have expected that with the same pixel ratio the buttons would scale. I am obviously misunderstanding this. What setting would I use to get the buttons to scale?

Comment: A dimension in `dp` should be approximately the same physical size regardless of screen density. If you want different UIs based upon screen size, you are welcome to do that too: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think Android should scale your app without anything that you tell it to do?

"dp" simply makes things look the same across devices with different densities (higher density makes use of more pixels) . It won't make things larger or smaller, and it's a good thing since you don't want text to be either huge or too small to be able to read.

For text, BTW, it's usually better to use "sp" so that the user might be able to change its size (because people might have eyes problems to read small letters).

If you wish to scale things, you can either create your own mechanism (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android)) or use openGL .