# Automatically change textSize to fit layout width

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a TextView with layout_width set to match_parent. Is there any way to automatically assign a textSize value to try to fit the text to that width without wrapping? I need that text in a single line but as big as possible.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy, but there's a guide to doing this in the first answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android).