# adjust Dynamic textview array in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

> hello friends i am new android, i need your help.
>
> my problem is  i am adding textview array in linear layout Dynamic
>   way. but when it's reach near device screen width its not wrap
>   contenting .
>
> like this way :
>
> [image]
>
> here is my xml file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative_read_image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar_alphabet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/single_gridviewHeight"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_alphabet"
    android:paddingTop="7dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linelay_bar_alphabet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_read_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bar_alphabet"
    android:background="@drawable/background_reading9"
    android:gravity="left" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linelay_wordIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar_alphabet"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbttn_help"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onclick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/help1" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_help"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onclick"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>
```

> code for adding textview in linear layout

```
 public static ArrayList<TextView> sentence(String[] arr) {

if (linelay_wordIn.getChildCount() > 0)
    linelay_wordIn.removeAllViews();
if (allTextView != null) {
    allTextView.remove(txt);
    allTextView.clear();
    System.out.println("hello remove all textview here");
} else {
    System.out.println("hello all textview array is null here");
}

String str1 = "";

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str1 = str1 + arr[i].toString();
    System.out.println(" senctence separte in word " + arr[i]
        + " words" + arr.length);
}
/* listview for getting textview */

System.out.println("sentence " + str1.toString() + "str1 length :: "
    + str1.length());
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) contextG
    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - 20;
txt = new TextView[arr.length];

for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

    txt[j] = new TextView(contextG);
    txt[j].setId(j);
    // txt[j].setTag(sent_audio1[j]);
    txt[j].setBackgroundResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    txt[j].setTextSize(60);
    txt[j].setTypeface(
        Typeface.createFromAsset(contextG.getAssets(), "TIMES.TTF"),
        Typeface.BOLD);
    // if (arr.length >= 5) {
    //
    // } else {
    txt[j].setText(arr[j]);
    // }
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    lp.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
    txt[j].setLayoutParams(lp);
    txt[j].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt[j].setClickable(true);
    txt[j].setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
    txt[j].setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    txt[j].setFocusable(true);
    txt[j].setOnTouchListener(myListener);

    // System.out.println("txt[j]" + j + "id " + txt[j].getId());
    allTextView.add(txt[j]); /* add textview into arraylist */
    // System.out.println("id" + allTextView.get(j).getId() +
    // "text "
    // + allTextView.get(j).getText().toString());
    // System.out.println("x" + allTextView.get(j).getX() + "y "
    // + allTextView.get(j).getY());
    // if (linelay_wordIn.getChildCount() > 5) {
    // txt[j].setText(arr[j] + "\n");
    // }
    linelay_wordIn.addView(txt[j], lp);

    // linelay_wordIn.getChildAt(j).getX();
    // System.out.println("y " +
    // linelay_wordIn.getChildAt(j).getX());

}

return allTextView;

}
```

> i dnot know how to solve this problem very quick way or easy way.
>   if anybody can suggest better way that will helpful to me.
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: i cant decrease font size ...

Comment: try this txt[j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Comment: try this and let me know:-- txt[j].setMaxLines(10);

Comment: txt[j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  also not working...i  added textview in linear layout not text

Answer (score 0):

Read this post! some others also faced the same problem.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android/)

but there is one little solution i can suggest you is adding TextView.setMaxLines() property 
but this is also much limited, Anyways try this

Comment: my question is about textview adjustment , i have no problem with textview size