# Where is the auto-resizable TextView used in the GDK Card class?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

So the GDK provides the `Card` class which is quite nice for creating cards at runtime.  Especially useful is the `setText()` method for cards which automatically sets the font size to best fit the card, based on the amount of text and the available space.

This feature would be very useful in cases where I want to display text on cards, but cannot use the `Card` class due to customisation needs.  I've thus been looking in the GDK to find where this resizable text view is defined, but I don't see it anywhere.

Is it publicly exposed somewhere or is there source code for download?

Answer (score 0):

I think for a custom layout you'll have to use custom code to handle font sizing, like people have done for other Android apps. For example,

- [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)
- [Auto-fit TextView for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android)