# How Google Keep resizes the text of a note?

Tags: android, algorithm, text, google-keep

I've been developing an application similar to the Google Keep, and was wondering how actually they allocate the text size to a note (algo)?

- Do they just allocate size depending upon the Note length?
- Or they also check for Card Dimensions i-e card width etc?

Its a bit confusing, because sometimes notes have equal card size dimensions with font-difference, and sometimes notes have both different size dimensions and text size?

So basically, the Question is, What is the algorithm/method to calculate the text size for a note?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `auto-fit TextView` for this & add it in `RecycleView` or `ListView`(whatever you want) item layout. here is one of stack answer of [AutoFit-TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android) and source code from github [android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)

***apply max text size in `TextView` then it automatically adjust if there is more text***

[image]

> Do they just allocate size depending upon the Note length

No,

> Or they also check for Card Dimensions i-e card width etc

No

just make you TexView size wrapcontent its allow you to add all text in textview like `whatsup chat thread`.

---

Edited

you have to manage like below way

***in Google keep text size depend of words. *text length is 10* then maximum text size. *text length is 30* then medium textsize and *more then 50* then small text***

***they are using two typeface one is for title and another is for text message***

Comment: they not only resize the text, but also change the typeface according to the text! See the attached img, Secondly, according to the above library, we may have to give the line numbers to auto-fit the text but then question arrises, how the line numbers will be calculated? And i'm sure GOOGLE isn't using the above approach :)