# Aligning two textviews by width

Tags: android, textview

I have two textviews, a title and a subtitle, just like:

[image]

As strings are located on `strings.xml`, they might change their width depending on the language, it can be larger or shorter.

**Doubt:** 
Is there a way I can keep subtitle's TextView2 both left and right edges always aligned to the Title's textView edges, no matter what? I imagine android would have to adjust the font size automatically to match both edges.

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no "fit width" for font size. There are some libraries and / or code snippets that help do that, but if your text gets much longer in other languages that might not be the best idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own implementation to handle this case. Please check this link which got more info and a solution.

[Auto-fit TextView for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android)