# Android set text in TextView to fill entire TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-textattributes

I know if I have a `TextView` I can set the width and height using `LayoutParams` my question is: Is there a way I can programatically set a TextView so that its text automatically fills the height and width of the `TextView`

A few differences between this question and the other question that has been asked, is that

1. I do not want to edit or copy the `TextView` it should be non-interactive.

and

2. I am setting the width and height once.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do this. Check this SO page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android

Comment: Check out [this project](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview).