# ObjectAnimator pixlated TextView

Tags: android, animation

I face a problem when scaling up TextViews and Checkboxes in Samsung GT-N5110 android version 4.1.2
the following image appears after scaling up the TextView there's textview inside i want to scale it up i did try enabling scale animation in developer options with no use i also did try nineoldandroid.jar.

[image]

here's my code inside fargment:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
        textView = (AutoResizeTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
     ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(linearLayout , "scaleY", 500).setDuration(500).start();
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(linearLayout , "scaleX", 500).setDuration(500).start();
        }
```

layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/prayer_background">

            <com.example.views.AutoResizeTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/aboutUs"
                android:textSize="5sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

prayer_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <corners android:radius="10dip" />
        <stroke
            android:width="5dip"
            android:color="@color/mainColor" />
        <solid android:color="@color/mainColor" />
    </shape>
```

**Update:**

I did try AutoResizeText and ScaleableTextView mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android/31486082#31486082):
I get the following result:
[image]

Comment: You should make your quesition more clean.

Comment: you can tell me how :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to scale up circle that includes text i'll add more details

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is in the attached image the text is pixlated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107561/discussion-between-tiny-sunlight-and-muhammad).

Comment: I'm going to sleep now.You can leave me a message if you don't understand.

Comment: Did you try experimenting with `myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`? I have seen problems in the past with upscaling and using the wrong layer type, especially on older devices.

Comment: I did try that same result

Answer (score 0):

```
private int dp2px(float dp){
            return (int) (dp * activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
        }
        private doScale(){
            final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_main);
            final int oldSize = dp2px(30);
            final float scale = 2f;
            final float textSizeOld = textView.getTextSize();
            ValueAnimator valueAnimatorLarge = ValueAnimator.ofInt(1,100 );
            valueAnimatorLarge.setDuration(500);
            valueAnimatorLarge.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    float currentScale = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue()/100f;
                    layoutParams.width = (int) (scale*oldSize*currentScale);
                    layoutParams.height = layoutParams.width;
                    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    textView.setTextSize(scale*textSizeOld*currentScale);
                }
            });
            valueAnimatorLarge.start();
        }
```

Comment: float currentScale = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue()/100f;

cast exception from float to int