# Is it possible for content (size) to match parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

If I have a text in a button that has `match_parent`, is it possible to make the `textSize` as big as possible without cropping the text? Preferably in `XML` and with a maximum setting so it doesn't become too big. In other words I'd like it to make it just fit if it would split a long word, otherwise stick to the preset size.

Comment: can you post a screeen shot

Comment: https://github.com/erchenger/SizeAdjustingTextView once check this

Answer (score 0):

[This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android), but it does not look clearly in my opinion you should to try to change your design to avoid this requirement