# Android textSize unit to fit text in parent with exact size in dp

Tags: android, text-size

I have a 32dp * 32dp TextView and a single "A" character in center with size of 10pt. In my device "A" is exactly fit to bounds (from top and bottom and looks good) but in other devices it is smaller or overflows the bounds.

Does **dp**, **ds**, **px** or other units help? (please remind I am not searching for this [automatic resizeable font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android) where I have **exact height** of 32dp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp` as the unit of measurement to set text size to support different densities across devices.
Also, read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) for a good explanation of `dp`/`sp`.