# Autofit EditText for Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have EditText with height, which depends on the device

User writes his or her text and I want to limit EditText by the height (number of symbols). Height can't be a constant, as a solution I can change size of a font

Are there any best practices, did anybody face this issue?

The only one good solution, I've already found is https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText

Comment: isn't `wrap_content` do what you want?

Comment: I am using it now, but if text takes more place, then a height of EditText scroll appears, but it's not ok, because I take a screenshot, and not all text  is on the screen

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to solve the issue - need to create a Listener, as Mohsen said:

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextLinesLimiter(EditText, 4));
```

And a class will be a following:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.icu.text.StringSearch;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditTextLinesLimiter implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText editText;
    private int maxLines;
    private String lastValue = "";               

    public EditTextLinesLimiter(EditText editText, int maxLines) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.maxLines = maxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        lastValue = charSequence.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        if (editText.getLineCount() > maxLines) {

            int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart() - 1;
            editText.setText(lastValue);

            if (selectionStart >= editText.length()) {

                selectionStart = editText.length();
            }
            editText.setSelection(selectionStart);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can limit your EditText height by number of lines properties, if it helps:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:minLines="2" />
```

They are totally related to Fonts and also can be edited programatically:

```
editText.setLines(3);
editText.setMaxLines(5);
editText.setMinLines(2);
```

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. Can we block user not to go to Line 6 and so on? Or show just first 5 lines?

Comment: Yes, you can limit lines with MaxLines property to 5.

Comment: No, MaxLines is a limitation for viewing,  but not enterning\editing. So user will be able to view only 5 lines, but enter 100500+

Comment: If you want to limit user, then you have to add TextWatcher to your EditText using addTextChangedListener and count **\n** characters on afterTextChanged event.

Comment: I suppose to implement some validation, however thanks for help, Mohsen

Comment: I have resolved the issue, I'll update you answer with my solution and mark it as a rigth answer in Actitme few days