# Android Edittext: not autoresizable

Tags: android, android-edittext

As TextView has autosize property that's weird that its' child EditText has't. There should be a reason for that but I could't find any links on that topic.

Comment: You can see This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053834/autosizing-edittext) in Stack.I hope it has some good ideas.

Comment: @Haileapp I saw this answer. But my question is not about implementation. I want to find out the reason. Maybe this is a bad practice to resize input text size. If so there should be some links

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to `EditText` official documentation and open [Inherited XML attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#inhattrs) you can find that 'EditText` actually has auto-size properties:

[image]

Comment: I saw this, it is available from api 26 only, though autotextsize for TextView is in support library. And as far as I know the same situation in IOS - available for text labels only. So you didn't answer my question: What is the reason for avoiding autotextsize for edit fields?