# Java android autosize Text in Edittext

Tags: android

This is my editText:

```
      <EditText
                android:id="@+id/max_deep_bin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This edittext have to be in one line so I put a parameter :   `android:singleLine="true"` but when a text is too long I want to change a textSize how I can do this ?

Comment: write maxlines 1

Comment: @AravindV it does not change a text size in editttext

Comment: you want change textsize depends upon the characters right ?

Comment: you can not change text size as per your question's requirement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autosizing EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053834/autosizing-edittext)

Comment: try this one https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 0):

Use `editText.setTextSize(...)`

Parameter will be a float value `size` and the text size of `editText` will be set to `size` sp

If you want a different measurement unit other than sp, use a predefined integer value `unit` before the `size` parameter. What are those predefined values you ask..?

- COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP : Device Independent Pixels (DP)
- COMPLEX_UNIT_IN : Inches
- COMPLEX_UNIT_MM : Millimetres
- COMPLEX_UNIT_PT : Points
- COMPLEX_UNIT_PX : Raw Pixels
- COMPLEX_UNIT_SP : Scaled Pixels

For example, if you need the text size to be 20px, use

```
editText.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20.0)
```

Hope this helps..!

Answer (score 0):

Android introduces the auto text size increase option

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
      android:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes" />


    <resources>
      <array name="autosize_text_sizes">
        <item>10sp</item>
        <item>12sp</item>
        <item>20sp</item>
        <item>40sp</item>
        <item>100sp</item>
      </array>
    </resources>

    I Hope this will work!
```