# Dealing with long Strings & TextView behavior

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout, textview

I’m developing an android app that gets objects from a server and shows them in a simple list.

I’m trying to figure out how to deal with long object’s titles :
Every title populates a designated multi-line TextView.
 If a title is longer than 16 characters, it messes with my desired UI.

There are two scenarios I need to solve -

1). If the title is longer than 16 characters & contains more than one word, I need to split the words into different lines (I tried to `.split("")` and `.trim()`, but I don’t want to use another view, just break a line in the same one, and the use in `("")` seems unreliable to me).

2). If the title is longer than 16 characters and contains only one long word, I only need to change font size specifically.

Any ideas for a good and reliable solution?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi this link is helping to solve your issue.
https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

Comment: @NShemesh have you try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like below it will work as you need

```
String title; //your title

//find length of your title
int length = title.length();

if (length>16){
string[] titles = myString.split("\\s+");

int size = titles.length;

if (size < 2){
      yourTextview.setText(title);
   // reduce the text size of your textview
}else {
  String newTitle= "";
for (int i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
  newTitle = titles[i]+"\n"
}
  yourTextview.setText(newTitle);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `SpannableString` for a single view

For title:

```
 SpannableString titleSpan = new SpannableString("title String");
 titleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.3f), 0, titleSpan.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

for Message

```
SpannableString messageSpan = new SpannableString("Message String");
messageSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.0f), 0, messageSpan.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

set in TextView

```
 tvTermsPolicyHeading.setText(TextUtils.concat(titleSpan, messageSpan));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split and then concatenate the words using "\n" if there are more than one words.
In case of long word
You can see this question here
[Auto-fit TextView for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(title.split(" ").size > 1){
    String line1 = title.substring(0, 16);
    int end = line1.lastIndexOf(" ");
    titleTextView.setText(title.substring(0,end) + "\n" + 
    title.substring(end+1,title.size-1);
}else{
    titleTextView.setText(title);
    titleTextView.setTextSize(yourTextSize);
}
```

this code should work perfectly for your case.