# TextView is not Auto Resizing

Tags: java, android

I have a text view in Linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_text"
            android:text="hello"
            android:background="#55000000"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And in build.gradle I have

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0'
}
```

But It is showing a fixed size (minimum size ) text only. It is not auto resizing depending on phone width;

Comment: Refer from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android

Comment: `android:layout_weight="0.8"` remove this line.why did you write it?

Comment: Because there is a parent layout above it and parent has more components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `wrap_content` for `layout_height` or `layout_width` as it might not work. You need to use fixed value for `layout_height` in your case.

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

> If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the
>   value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes
>   of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.

Comment: In XML it will still be TextView right?. As I am only setting text Dynamically from Java. And not doing any auto resizing thing from Java

Comment: Yes. After removing wrap_content in Height it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a fixed value to either layout_width or layout_height  for auto text sizing property to work.

Answer (score 0):

check this method:

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(TextView textview, int autoSizeTextType)
```

it will look like this

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(
        findViewById(R.id.detail_text), 
        TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM)
```

also from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#setting-textview-autosize *Using support library*

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
      app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
      app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
      app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Isn't XML declarations enough? From docs, it looks like xml declarations should be enough.