# How to Auto Size text by height programmaticaly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I have a vertical LinearLayout with a height of 32dp and i want to fit two TextView of 16dp each. The length of the text is different and i want it to always nicely fit in a single line.

I have tried with an [AutoTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) and with a classic TextView + AutoSizing by TextViewCompat but none of these really work. My text shrink a bit but always finish to be crop at the bottom.

Here the base code

```
LinearLayout adressTextLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
adressTextLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

adressTextLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    //icon_size_big = 32dp
    (int) (activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.icon_size_big))));

boolean noAdress = true;

//First line with Country, Region and department
if(!mondialAdress.isEmpty()){
    noAdress = false;
    TextView tx = Utils.createAutoFitTextView(activity, mondialAdress, true, (int) (activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.icon_size_big)/2));
    tx.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
    adressTextLayout.addView(tx);
}
//Second line with adress, postal code and city
if(!localAdress.isEmpty()){
    noAdress = false;
    TextView tx = Utils.createAutoFitTextView(activity, localAdress, true, (int) (activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.icon_size_big)/2));
    adressTextLayout.addView(tx);
}
//Default line in case we didn't found any adress
if(noAdress){
    adressTextLayout.addView(Utils.createAutoFitTextView(activity, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.hint_provide_information), true, 0));
}
```

Here is the createAutoFitTextView() function with TextViewCompat

```
public static TextView createAutoFitTextView(Activity activity, String text, boolean singleLine, int maxHeight) {
    TextView textView = new AutofitTextView(activity);

    textView.setText(text);

    //MATCH_PARENT by default
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, maxHeight > 0 ? maxHeight : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

    //Auto Sizing by TextViewCompat
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);

    if(singleLine){
        textView.setSingleLine(true);
    }

    return textView;
}
```

Here the function with AutoFitTextView

```
public static AutofitTextView createAutoFitTextView(Activity activity, String text, boolean singleLine, int maxHeight) {
    AutofitTextView textView = new AutofitTextView(activity);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, maxHeight != -1 ? maxHeight : ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

    textView.setText(text);
    if(singleLine){
        textView.setSingleLine(true);
    }
    return textView;
}
```

Here a the result :

- With [TextViewCompat](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview)
- With AutoFillTextView:

[image: With AutoFillTextView]

Comment: I'm using this in my project and it's working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017165/auto-fit-textview-for-android/21851239

Comment: Thanks @Djaf, almost work, with this one it's got crop at the end... It resize it a bit but not enough..