# Is it possible to have TextView with maxLines=2 but if the text has one single long word not break it in 2 lines?

Tags: android, textview

I have  a TextView and I set text which I receive from Backend.
the text is either from 1 to 3 words.
Maximum the textview can be 2 lines.
I am using `setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration`
and `text.breakStrategy = LineBreaker.BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE`
And I don't have any success.
wondering is it possible if the text is single word I don't want to split it. I would like to have it in single line with small textSize. if the text is 2 words and long I am fine to show it in 2 lines. The problem is it always breaks the word in 2 lines if it is long while I don't want.

Comment: If @Rinat's answer is not enough(since you also mention a smaller textSize), maybe you'll want to use a custom [Auto-fit TextView for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017165). Otherwise, Android doesn't offer a standard resizeable TextView.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that comes to my mind is before setting the text to a textview, check whether text has spaces in it.
If it has  not that that means it's a single word, so set ptogrammatically maxlines to 1, otherwise set maxlines to 2.

EDIT: I missed text size part. I use this library for autoresizing and it worked so far https://github.com/jivimberg/AutoResizeTextView

Answer (score 0):

it's automatically handled in `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText` and just set `android:maxLines="2"`

remove all other properties you set